# R: counting occurrences in less than x minutes

Tags: r, date

I am reading from a csv file a DDBB from a CRM (operations), and it looks like this:

```
OP_ID   CRD_NO    TRN_DATE
1       2189761   04/01/18  13:19:00
2       2189761   04/01/18  13:33:00
3       2189761   04/01/18  19:25:00
4       97429     02/01/18  13:46:00
5       97429     02/01/18  19:42:00
6       20390     04/01/18  13:16:00
7       20390     04/01/18  18:32:00
8       20390     05/01/18  20:16:00
9       20390     05/01/18  10:55:00
10      673863    04/01/18  12:27:00
11      673863    04/01/18  18:43:00
12      673863    04/01/18  19:11:00
```

Now I need to add a new column to include a Flag when, for the same `CRD_NO`, there are **at least (K) number of operations that happen in the same day**, but they occur with a difference of **(J)** minutes.

For this example, let's say it is necessary that there are **at least 3 operations** with a **difference of 10 minutes**.

Then, the output should be:

```
OP_ID   CRD_NO    TRN_DATE              FLAG
1       2189761   04/01/18  13:19:00     1
2       2189761   04/01/18  13:33:00     1
3       2189761   04/01/18  19:25:00     1
4       97429     02/01/18  13:46:00     0
5       97429     02/01/18  19:42:00     0
6       20390     04/01/18  13:16:00     0
7       20390     04/01/18  18:32:00     0
8       20390     05/01/18  20:16:00     0
9       20390     05/01/18  10:55:00     0
10      673863    04/01/18  12:27:00     1
11      673863    04/01/18  18:43:00     1
12      673863    04/01/18  19:11:00     1
```

I am quite new at R, and I have done it using too many loops (as I did it in Matlab before).

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>% 
mutate(timestamp = strptime(paste(CRD_NO, TRN_DATE), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
group_by(CRD_NO, TRN_DATE) %>%
mutate(FLAG = as.integer(
         n() > 3 &
         (max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) > 10 * 60)))
```

We convert your timstamps to an actual datetime class so we can subtract them, group by the id and the day, and use a simple condition.

Note that "with a difference of 10 minutes" is a little vague. I interpreted it as "the difference between the first and last time is at least 10 minutes".

Comment: The difference of 10 minutes should be between each operation. And it should happen at least with 3 operations in the example.

Comment: Yes, my `n() > 3` handles the "at least 3 operations. But maybe you should edit your question to clarify about the 10 minutes. If there are operations as 1:00, 1:05, 2:00, and 3:00, does that count? What about 1:00, 1:08, 1:16, 1:24, 1:32? I can find three (1:00, 1:16, 1:32) that are more than 10 apart...

Comment: There must be 10 minutes between consecutive operations. In your example (1:00, 1:08, 1:16, 1:24, 1:32), none of the operations would have a Flag. Also, in the code proposal, there is no condition to check if it happens in the same day, right?

Comment: Sorry, use the wrong column in the grouping. Adding `TRN_DATE` to the `group_by()` makes all the subsequent operations happen only in the same day.

Comment: Okay, and so my first example `1:00, 1:05, 2:00, 3:00`, also gets no flag, right? But `1:00, 1:05, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00` would get flags just for the 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: Exactly, they would get flag the last 4 operations: 1:05, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00

Comment: I keep providing 2 examples in a single comment, but you only respond to one of them :(. It sounds like if there are multiple transactions with 10 minutes of each other, you only count the *last* one, is that right? So if there was `1:00, 1:30, 1:39, 1:45, 2:00`, what then? No flags?

Comment: There has to be at least 3 operations with a frequency less than 10 minutes in a row. In you last example, 1&2 are OK,  and 4&5 also, pero there are not 3 operations in a raw.